# Whitelisting all the Google JDBC Service IP addresses in CPanel

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, cpanel, google-apps

I am trying to connect a Google Docs extension to a MySQL database via JDBC Service. The MySQL database is running on a shared server that requires using CPanel. CPanel only lets me add one whitelist rule at a time, and I can only use the % wildcard character (which matches to 0 or more of any type of character). I wrote a script to generate rules in this format from the IP address ranges, but there are more than 300 of them. I'm trying to find an easier way to do this.

Is there a domain name for the Google JDBC Service that I can whitelist instead of the IP address ranges? Does CPanel have a more efficient whitelisting mechanism that I'm not aware of? Is there a program that could automate filling out CPanel's webform with my whitelist?

Here is the CPanel-formatted whitelist I generated, in case someone with the same problem finds my question.

```
64.18.0.%
64.18.1.%
64.18.2.%
64.18.3.%
64.18.4.%
64.18.5.%
64.18.6.%
64.18.7.%
64.18.8.%
64.18.9.%
64.18.10.%
64.18.11.%
64.18.12.%
64.18.13.%
64.18.14.%
64.233.160.%
64.233.161.%
64.233.162.%
64.233.163.%
64.233.164.%
64.233.165.%
64.233.166.%
64.233.167.%
64.233.168.%
64.233.169.%
64.233.170.%
64.233.171.%
64.233.172.%
64.233.173.%
64.233.174.%
64.233.175.%
64.233.176.%
64.233.177.%
64.233.178.%
64.233.179.%
64.233.180.%
64.233.181.%
64.233.182.%
64.233.183.%
64.233.184.%
64.233.185.%
64.233.186.%
64.233.187.%
64.233.188.%
64.233.189.%
64.233.190.%
66.102.0.%
66.102.1.%
66.102.2.%
66.102.3.%
66.102.4.%
66.102.5.%
66.102.6.%
66.102.7.%
66.102.8.%
66.102.9.%
66.102.10.%
66.102.11.%
66.102.12.%
66.102.13.%
66.102.14.%
66.249.80.%
66.249.81.%
66.249.82.%
66.249.83.%
66.249.84.%
66.249.85.%
66.249.86.%
66.249.87.%
66.249.88.%
66.249.89.%
66.249.90.%
66.249.91.%
66.249.92.%
66.249.93.%
66.249.94.%
72.14.192.%
72.14.193.%
72.14.194.%
72.14.195.%
72.14.196.%
72.14.197.%
72.14.198.%
72.14.199.%
72.14.200.%
72.14.201.%
72.14.202.%
72.14.203.%
72.14.204.%
72.14.205.%
72.14.206.%
72.14.207.%
72.14.208.%
72.14.209.%
72.14.210.%
72.14.211.%
72.14.212.%
72.14.213.%
72.14.214.%
72.14.215.%
72.14.216.%
72.14.217.%
72.14.218.%
72.14.219.%
72.14.220.%
72.14.221.%
72.14.222.%
72.14.223.%
72.14.224.%
72.14.225.%
72.14.226.%
72.14.227.%
72.14.228.%
72.14.229.%
72.14.230.%
72.14.231.%
72.14.232.%
72.14.233.%
72.14.234.%
72.14.235.%
72.14.236.%
72.14.237.%
72.14.238.%
72.14.239.%
72.14.240.%
72.14.241.%
72.14.242.%
72.14.243.%
72.14.244.%
72.14.245.%
72.14.246.%
72.14.247.%
72.14.248.%
72.14.249.%
72.14.250.%
72.14.251.%
72.14.252.%
72.14.253.%
72.14.254.%
74.125.%
173.194.%
207.126.144.%
207.126.145.%
207.126.146.%
207.126.147.%
207.126.148.%
207.126.149.%
207.126.150.%
207.126.151.%
207.126.152.%
207.126.153.%
207.126.154.%
207.126.155.%
207.126.156.%
207.126.157.%
207.126.158.%
209.85.128.%
209.85.129.%
209.85.130.%
209.85.131.%
209.85.132.%
209.85.133.%
209.85.134.%
209.85.135.%
209.85.136.%
209.85.137.%
209.85.138.%
209.85.139.%
209.85.140.%
209.85.141.%
209.85.142.%
209.85.143.%
209.85.144.%
209.85.145.%
209.85.146.%
209.85.147.%
209.85.148.%
209.85.149.%
209.85.150.%
209.85.151.%
209.85.152.%
209.85.153.%
209.85.154.%
209.85.155.%
209.85.156.%
209.85.157.%
209.85.158.%
209.85.159.%
209.85.160.%
209.85.161.%
209.85.162.%
209.85.163.%
209.85.164.%
209.85.165.%
209.85.166.%
209.85.167.%
209.85.168.%
209.85.169.%
209.85.170.%
209.85.171.%
209.85.172.%
209.85.173.%
209.85.174.%
209.85.175.%
209.85.176.%
209.85.177.%
209.85.178.%
209.85.179.%
209.85.180.%
209.85.181.%
209.85.182.%
209.85.183.%
209.85.184.%
209.85.185.%
209.85.186.%
209.85.187.%
209.85.188.%
209.85.189.%
209.85.190.%
209.85.191.%
209.85.192.%
209.85.193.%
209.85.194.%
209.85.195.%
209.85.196.%
209.85.197.%
209.85.198.%
209.85.199.%
209.85.200.%
209.85.201.%
209.85.202.%
209.85.203.%
209.85.204.%
209.85.205.%
209.85.206.%
209.85.207.%
209.85.208.%
209.85.209.%
209.85.210.%
209.85.211.%
209.85.212.%
209.85.213.%
209.85.214.%
209.85.215.%
209.85.216.%
209.85.217.%
209.85.218.%
209.85.219.%
209.85.220.%
209.85.221.%
209.85.222.%
209.85.223.%
209.85.224.%
209.85.225.%
209.85.226.%
209.85.227.%
209.85.228.%
209.85.229.%
209.85.230.%
209.85.231.%
209.85.232.%
209.85.233.%
209.85.234.%
209.85.235.%
209.85.236.%
209.85.237.%
209.85.238.%
209.85.239.%
209.85.240.%
209.85.241.%
209.85.242.%
209.85.243.%
209.85.244.%
209.85.245.%
209.85.246.%
209.85.247.%
209.85.248.%
209.85.249.%
209.85.250.%
209.85.251.%
209.85.252.%
209.85.253.%
209.85.254.%
216.239.32.%
216.239.33.%
216.239.34.%
216.239.35.%
216.239.36.%
216.239.37.%
216.239.38.%
216.239.39.%
216.239.40.%
216.239.41.%
216.239.42.%
216.239.43.%
216.239.44.%
216.239.45.%
216.239.46.%
216.239.47.%
216.239.48.%
216.239.49.%
216.239.50.%
216.239.51.%
216.239.52.%
216.239.53.%
216.239.54.%
216.239.55.%
216.239.56.%
216.239.57.%
216.239.58.%
216.239.59.%
216.239.60.%
216.239.61.%
216.239.62.%
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, have you found a solution? I'm trying to whitelist the IPs as per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases

Answer (score 2):

Oday,

Your suggestion won't work as the IP ranges aren't all inclusive.  Here is the list that Google says to whitelist.

As an example...how do I white list 64.18.0.x to 64.18.15.x

---

I should have looked harder in stackoverflow.  For others that stumble upon this post, here is the answer that I found at

[Whitelist IP addresses ranges using cPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583279/whitelist-ip-addresses-ranges-using-cpanel?rq=1)

> 64.18.0-15.%
>
> 64.233.160-191.%
>
> 64.102.0-15.%
>
> 66.249.80-95.%
>
> 72.14.192-255.%
>
> 74.125.%
>
> 173.194.%
>
> 207.126.144-159.%
>
> 209.85.128-255.%
>
> 216.239.32-63.%

Answer (score 1):

This is long overdue, but the easiest solution is to use the % wildcard like this to make it easier:

```
64.18.%.%
64.233.%.%
66.102.%.%
...etc
```