# Whitelist IP addresses ranges using cPanel

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, cpanel

I am trying to connect a Google Docs extension to a MySQL database via JDBC Service. For that, I have to whitelist the IP addresses as per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases

How can I do this quickly using CPanel, since there are a few hundreds of them?

One by one seems like an awful work to do......

Comment: Try adding it as 192.168.0.128-255, if you want to add IP ranges from 168.0.128 to 168.0.255. Hope that helps!

Comment: I added 64.18.0.0-255 to add 64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255 and it accepted!
How do I add 64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

This was a HUGE issue for me. This was my solution.

64.18.0-15.%

64.233.160-191.%

64.102.0-15.%

66.249.80-95.%

72.14.192-255.%

74.125.%

173.194.%

207.126.144-159.%

209.85.128-255.%

216.239.32-63.%

Comment: Bless your kind soul, Darth Blumpkin. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this... instantly fixed the issue for which I've been looking for a solution for hours!

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, `192.168.0.128-255`  this one adds IP from `192.168.0.128 to 192.168.0.255`. So try giving it as `192.168.0.128-15.255`.

Also for `64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255`, you could try giving it as `64.233.160.0-191.255`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Right you will have to add that IP range in allow host list though cPanel >> Mysql >> Remote Mysql